# Understanding the Union Axiom. Proving $x \cup y := \{z: z\in x \lor z\in y\}$ is a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Hi guys I'm really new to set theory and I'm trying to well understand the Union Axiom.

First of all, the Union Axiom state the following (at least this is the definition I have):

$$\forall \,x\ \exists\, u\ (\forall\, y\ (\exists\, z\ (z\in x \land y\in z) \rightarrow y \in u))$$

This axiom (if I'm not mistaken) has the immediate consequence of the class $\bigcup x:=\{y: \exists z(z\in x \land y\in z)\}$ being a set. Now, how do I prove from this fact that, for every sets $x$ and $y$ the class  $x \cup y := \{z: z\in x \lor z\in y\}$ is, infact, a set? I wanted to use the separation schema but I am not yet familiar with the use of it.

Thank you guys, any help is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the axiom of pairing to construct the set $\{x,y\}$, and apply the axiom of union on this set, to prove the existence of $x\cup y$.